# How to highlight cells in excel if a condition formula is met?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried conditional formatting, however, the condition I need to highlight a cell is more specific than just "equals to" or "less than" ... The criteria a cell needs to match to be highlighted is if it is 80% of max or minimum of the values limits. For example, if the value required is 10 +- 5 and the value measured is 12 (15*.8) or 4 (5*.8) it should be highlighted. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: should it *only* highlight if it's exactly 80% or is there range where it will highlight?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added a picture to help explain. In the example I posted, the 'required value' is 10 with upper and lower limits of 15 and 5. The measured values that need to be highlighted would be 12 and 4 because they are 80% of the upper and lower limits. To answer your question about the range, 80-100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just built and tested this formula and it works:

```
=OR(AND(F4>=(($C$4+$D$4)*0.8),F4<=($C$4+$D$4)),AND(F4>=(($C$4-$E$4)*0.8),F4<=($C$4-$E$4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I really wish my programming classes were more focused on this kind of stuff rather than some language I'll probably never use considering the field I'm pursuing... Thanks for your help, you're a wonderful human!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your screenshot starts at cell A1.  You need two conditional formatting rules: one highlights when cell value = ($A$2+$B$2)*.8, the other highlights when the cell value = ($A$2-$B$3)*8.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, but say if I have more rows that contain more values that may or may not be the same, how can I conditionally format these new rows? If I select the whole range of the measured values and use the conditional formatting when cell value = ($A$2+B$2)*.8 it will compared all the measured values to the wrong reference other than which ever is in Row 2?

Comment: Well, don't use the $ then. That forces it not to change when you apply the formatting (which is what I thought you'd want).  If you want it to change for each row, then use = (A2+B2)*.8.  Then, when you drag this down, it becomes  = (A3+B3)*.8 and so on.